# How to arrange HTML elements like an NCAA bracket

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to write an NCAA bracket submission app, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to arrange the HTML elements in the shape of a bracket like [this](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3aANd9GcTob4rvfQnonqlh29fOmvGRJ67Pwd5v31an35JCVzbpH5i2YjXk). I'd like to use Bootstrap to keep the UI looking clean, but I'm not tied to it. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are great sample HTML/CSS brackets using divs be found [here](http://www.jimyi.com/blog/2009/04/09/html-tournament-brackets/). Alternatively, a good example of a two sided HTML/CSS bracket using unordered lists [can be found here](http://www.nbaplayoffsbracket.com/2013/). Check out the source code and figure out what works best for you.

I think a better approach would be to use an HTML `table` with a specific CSS `border` for each cell. I have created a rough example below. But you'll probably want to play around with it yourself, check out the links, and see what works best for your app. Best of luck!

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><p>1. Team Name</p></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><p>Team Name</p></td>
        <td rowspan="4"><p>Team Name</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-right:1px solid black"><p>4. Team Name</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ><p>2. Team Name</p></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><p>Team Name</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-right:1px solid black"><p>3. Team Name</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none;
}

td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 10em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

td p {
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 5px 2px 5px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3xCjb/)

Comment: The paragraph tags are a little inappropriate here since you aren't marking up paragraph content.  Span tags should be used instead.